# Build xfreerdp 1.1

Tags: remote-desktop

I have found instructions on how to build xfreerdp 1.0.1, but can't find anything about how to build version 1.1 instead.

Can someone please point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the directions for compiling XFreeRDP in their Github Wiki. This would seem to be what you're looking for.

- https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/wiki/Compilation

Even though they're marked as being for 1.0.1 I would assume that the steps haven't changed all that much.

Comment: That was what I found, but didn't try it because of the 1.0.1.  I'll give it a go anyway.  Thanks.

Comment: Yeah I wouldn't expect too much has changed in the compilation dept. from 1.0.1 to 1.1.

Comment: All seems to build fine except when I try to run it, i get `bash: /usr/bin/xfreerdp: No such file or directory`.

Comment: Usually tools get installed to `/usr/local/bin`, I'd check there.